# Finding all permutations which permute with (12)(34)

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

We are working in the symmetric group of 4, so I called it S4.

**For example, how would you go about finding the other permutations of (12)(34) other than itself, identity, (12), (34)?**

These are 4 and by conjugacy classes, we observe that there should be 8 permutations that commute with (12)(34). How would you figure them out? S4 is a big set so you cannot try them all out I guess there should be a method.

I have been looking but I cannot find or understand any method so please if you could make it simple for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Samuel the reason they brought up conjugacy classes, is because there's a theorem that states the size of an orbit of an element equals the index of its stabilizers. Since There are 3 conjugates of $(12)(34)$ we can deduce its centralizer has size 8.

Comment: A systematic way to find all 8 of them to write down the 8 versions of $(12)(34)$ in cycle notation, i.e.  $(21)(34)$, $(12)(43)$,  ... , $(43)(21)$. For each one, write $(12)(34)$ above it and map "down" to get a permutation that conjugates $(12)(34)$ to itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "write (12)(34) above it and map "down" "
 @Ned.

Comment: @Val,  For example, write (12)(34) above (34)(21) vertically lining up the two 2-cycles. Mapping "down" takes 1 to 3, 2 to 4, 3 to 2 and 4 to 1, which is to say the permutation obtained is (1324). Which means that (1324) conjugates (12)(34) to itself [in the form of (34)(12), if you want to think of the relabeling like that]. "Conjugating (12)(34) to itself" is the same as "commuting with (12)(34)."  The theme here is Conjugation = Relabeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of an efficient method to find all of them. However, one way that works in this case is to recall that if $\sigma\in S_4$, then $\sigma(12)(34)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(1)\sigma(2))(\sigma(3)\sigma(4)),$ so if $$\sigma(1)=3,\sigma(2)=4,\sigma(3)=1,\sigma(4)=2,$$
then $\sigma$ works. This tells us another element of the centralizer is $(13)(24).$ To find the others we can just look at the left coset $$(13)(24)\cdot\left<(12),(34)\right>.$$

Comment: Sorry, I m a bit confused about what σ does and why σ(12)(34)σ−1=(σ(1)σ(2))(σ(3)σ(4)). Also when you want to get new terms for σ(x), where x is between 1 and 4 I guess, how would you pick that image? @Melody

Comment: @Val edited my answer. The map $\sigma$ is just an arbitrary permutation. The formula I mentioned is just a standard formula for conjugation of a product of disjoint cycles. The reason I mentioned it, is because commuting with an element is equivalent to leaving it fixed under conjugation, so knowing how $(12)(34)$ acts under conjugation can help us determine which elements it commutes with. For example, if $\sigma$ commutes and $\sigma(1)=3,$ then we must have $\sigma(3)=1,2.$

Comment: What do you mean by " knowing how a (12)(34) acts under conjugation". I am sure there are some permutations of order 4 that will commute, how would you find those? @Melody

Comment: @Val Conjugation is a group action, so what I mean is basically what $\sigma(12)(34)\sigma^{-1}$ looks like for an arbitrary permutation. As for how to find the permutations of order 4, they'll be in the coset I mentioned $$(12)(34)\cdot\left<(12),(34)\right>.$$
Another way you could find them would be to notice that clearly we if $\sigma$ commutes with $(12)(34),$ and $\sigma$ is order 4, then $\sigma(1)=2$ implies $\sigma(2)=1$ by the formula I mentioned. So we must have $\sigma(1)=3,4.$ Choose $\sigma(1)=3,$ then $\sigma(3)\not=1,$ so $\sigma(3)=2$ by my last comment. Then $\sigma=(1324).$

Comment: If we were working in the symmetric group of 5, I guess I will have to choose σ(1)=3,4,5 (for an order 4 permutation that commutes) and I choose σ(1)=4, then σ(4)≠1 and then σ(4)=2,3,5 and I choose 5 then we have σ(5)=2,3 and I choose 3 . Then that means  σ=(1453)  commutes with (12)(34)? @Melody

Comment: @Val for $S_5$ we have to be a little more careful. Since $\sigma(12)(34)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(1)\sigma(2))(\sigma(3)\sigma(4))$ we cannot have $\sigma(x)=5$ for any $x\in\{1,2,3,4\}.$